# How to print out this RestAction / List

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I'm creating Discord-Bot for my Server. Normally i can print out Lists easy, but this RestActionList burns my brain :D.

Can someone tell me how to print out a RestAction?

```java
public class ShowBannsCommand implements ServerCommand {
    @Override
    public void performCommand(Member m, TextChannel channel, Message message, MessageReceivedEvent event, EventWaiter waiter) {
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();

        if(m.hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS)) {
            message.delete().queue();

            RestAction<List<Guild.Ban>> restAction = guild.retrieveBanList();

            EmbedBuilder builder = EmbedHelper.getDefault("Bannlist of " + guild.getName(), m.getAsMention() + ", here is the bannlist you requested.")
                    .setAuthor("Request by " + m.getUser().getName(), EmbedHelper.link, m.getUser().getEffectiveAvatarUrl())
                    .addField("Server:", guild.getName(), true)
                    .addField("Total banns:", "", true)
                    .addField("Banns:", "", false);
            channel.sendMessage(builder.build()).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Im using the JDA 4.2.0_214

Answer (score 0):

Use a queue callback:

```java
guild.retrievBanList().queue(list -> {
    // Note this list should have a hardcoded limit to prevent hitting the character limit
    String banList = list.stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    EmbedBuilder builder = EmbedHelper.getDefault("Bannlist of " + guild.getName(), m.getAsMention() + ", here is the bannlist you requested.")
                    .setAuthor("Request by " + m.getUser().getName(), EmbedHelper.link, m.getUser().getEffectiveAvatarUrl())
                    .addField("Server:", guild.getName(), true)
                    .addField("Total banns:", String.valueOf(list.size()), true)
                    .addField("Bans:", banList, false);
    channel.sendMessage(builder.build()).queue();
});
```